# Oracle user password expired / User does not exist in system

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I'm trying to login using **Oracle SQL Developer** I'm getting the error that the password has expired for the user.

So I moved into **SYS** and I tried to use **ALTER USER username IDENTIFIED BY "newpassword";** but there I'm getting error **ORA-01918 User does not exist in the system**.

How come that on the side of the connection using **Service name + Username + Password** it knows that the user exists and that the password has expired and on the other side of the connection where I'm using **SYS** it is saying that the user doesn't exist? What do I need to use to change the password?

I'm grateful for any help you can give me.

Comment: probably because you're in the wrong database, if 12.1 and higher, make sure your sys connection is on the pluggable database and not the container instance

Comment: I'm really bad at this, but what you are saying does sound right, I just don't remember how to do that. I'll try to find an example with that, I'm using XE21C

Comment: that's your problem then, in sql developer using SYS, you can open the DBA panel and the GUI will show the names of your pluggable databases, or you can use sql and run this 'show pdbs' -- that will give you the name of the instance to connect to

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't mean that, I know the name of the pluggable database (and yeah, if you have a saved connection you can easily see that inside the service name field in case you forget). I meant that I need to figure out how to access it using SYS to change the password for the user inside the pluggable database.

Comment: just use sys to connect to the pdb, or if you're in the container use the alter session set container = pdbname

Comment: When you said that I was on a website where there was an example using exactly what you said with alter session and then alter user, I've done that and now it is working. Thank you so much. I'm the sole developer for the project and I need a database for it, I know the basic of how to work with tables (adding/modifying data), but this with password expire isn't something I knew about/how to deal with. If you want you can add an answer to the question and in it combine your first comment and this last one as they were the solution to my problem, and I'll accept it as such.